# Zipping list of lists of lists lose decimals

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have a `list of lists of lists`:

```
[ [['1', '3.61912', '3.25558', '3.98787'], ['2', '5.35465', '4.98407', '5.82305'], ['3', '14.8184', '13.8878', '15.7686'], ['4', '0.278589', '0.25531', '0.302837'], ['5', '6.65982', '6.5638', '6.75855'], ['6', '0.05', '0', '0'], ['7', '0.00747086', '0.00620575', '0.00873102'], ['999', '0.', '0.', '0.'], ['998', '0.897487603306', '0.897487603306', '0.897487603306']], 
  [['1', '6.14332', '5.24188', '7.06803'], ['2', '5.73822', '5.31854', '6.27864'], ['3', '19.1023', '17.4778', '20.901'], ['4', '0.113164', '0.0963808', '0.13141'], ['5', '6.56417', '6.49081', '6.63889'], ['6', '0.05', '0', '0'], ['7', '0.00959252', '0.00842128', '0.0107523'], ['999', '0.', '0.', '0.'], ['998', '1.06972222222', '1.06972222222', '1.06972222222']], 
  [['1', '14.3005', '12.9284', '15.7195'], ['2', '5.25181', '4.8594', '5.77533'], ['3', '16.0296', '14.4662', '17.7269'], ['4', '0.263088', '0.216536', '0.316766'], ['5', '6.55534', '6.40134', '6.73512'], ['6', '0.05', '0', '0'], ['7', '0.00660481', '0.00493246', '0.00825176'], ['999', '0.', '0.', '0.'], ['998', '1.01537254902', '1.01537254902', '1.01537254902']] ]
```

playing with `zip`, to understand how it works, I printed:

```
print zip(*list[0]) --> [('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '999', '998'), ('3.61912', '5.35465', '14.8184', '0.278589', '6.65982', '0.05', '0.00747086', '0.', '0.897487603306'), ('3.25558', '4.98407', '13.8878', '0.25531', '6.5638', '0', '0.00620575', '0.', '0.897487603306'), ('3.98787', '5.82305', '15.7686', '0.302837', '6.75855', '0', '0.00873102', '0.', '0.897487603306')]
```

while if I zip again, I lose the decimals:

```
print zip(*values[0][3]) --> [('4', '0', '0', '0')]
```

Also, zipping for the last time results in the oddest:

```
print zip(*values[0][3][2]) --> [('0', '.', '2', '5', '5', '3', '1')]
```

Why does it lose the decimals? And why they are returned as single elements in the final zip? Finally: at a first glance, is this the best way to get lists and elements?

Comment: The behaviour for `zip(*values[0][3][2])` seems odd to me. It should return `[('0',), ('.',), ('2',), ('5',), ('5',), ('3',), ('1',)]` per the docs for 2.7 and all 3.x versions. What version are you on?

Answer (score 4):

You need to understand what you are zipping here. `values[0][3]` is a **single list**, one containing strings:

```
>>> values[0][3]
['4', '0.278589', '0.25531', '0.302837']
```

Each of these strings are sequences, but `zip()` can only produce pairings for the *shortest* sequence in the list. Here that is the first string, which contains just *one* character.

As such, you paired `'4'` with each of the `'0'` characters in the other 3 strings.

Next, when you give `zip()` just *one* sequence argument, you get the individual elements. You did that with your 3rd `zip()` call:

```
>>> values[0][3][2]
'0.25531'
>>> list(values[0][3][2])
['0', '.', '2', '5', '5', '3', '1']
```

That's just one sequence, and it is split into individual characters.

Answer (score 3):

The first `zip` works as expected.

When you zip `*values[0][3]` (i.e. `zip('4', '0.278589', '0.25531', '0.302837')`), it goes through each of the indices and puts the corresponding elements (characters of the strings) into the tuple.

For index `0`, it creates the tuple `('4', '0', '0', '0')` (because `'0'` is the first character at all the items except the first, where it is `4`) . Then, the first string runs out of characters, so `zip` stops (it only zips up to the end of the shortest iterable, consider using `itertools.izip_longest()` (`itertools.zip_longest` in Python 3) if you want other behaviour). That is why it returns only this one tuple.

Zipping `*values[0][3][2]` is like calling `zip('0.25531')` - because there is only one iterable argument (the string), the return value - per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#zip) - is

> an iterator of 1-tuples

i.e. each item is turned into a tuple, which should give `[('a',), ('b',), ('c',)]` when turned into a list (the behaviour described by the OP seems odd to me, I can't reproduce it).

Comment: So, how can I zip to the longest iterable? `itertools.zip_longest(*values[0][3])` returns an object `<itertools.izip_longest object at 0x1e9c22b8>`. Without the `*` the results is quite the same.

Comment: Your code was correct (with `*`). `itertools` functions usually return iterators, meaning that the actual objects are returned only as you iterate through the object. You can turn them into lists using `list` (for your example: `list(itertools.zip_longest(*values[0][3]))`)

Comment: this is bad! I had tried to `list()` it but I didn't like it. Do I have to "rebuild" each value by my self, avoiding the `None` too? How is this doable in one line ?

Comment: What do you mean with *"avoiding the `None`"*? Removing it from each item? Replacing it with something else?

Comment: I mean, the shortest iterable has just one character, the rest are `None`.

Comment: What did you expect when zipping to the longest iterable? Somehow, the output must be padded on shorter iterables. You can specify the fill value with `fillvalue=something` if you don't like `None`

Answer (score 2):

With this:

```
print zip(*values[0][3])
```

you are zipping `('4', '0.278589', '0.25531', '0.302837')`. Effectively, this will start iterating over 4 strings and will traverse them character by character. Since the shortest string is `4` with length 1, you will only see the first character of each string.